# Transfer some information from 1 workbook to another plus 1

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have 1 workbook with 4 sheets. Some of the information is auto entered from 1 sheet to another.  I do not save when closing out.  It is entered, printed and deleted.   I need to get some of the information off those sheets to a seperate workbook that I save. 
 Example: worksheet 1 info
          Name
          dob
          reason
          etc

I am wondering if I can transfer that information to another sheet to be entered on row one and then the next one on row 2 and so on.  Since I do not save the first workbook, will this work?

Answer (score 1):

Cheryl, see if this post on StackOverflow helps you out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415575/copy-and-paste-value-with-coloring.

It seems quite similar to your problem.  Since im only a 1 pt member on this site cant comment just yet.